# How to set it so that 1 of 2 columns is NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am going to open by saying that what's happening appears to not be a good practice but it is what myself and some other engineers have arrived at.

I have a table which has a column containing foreign keys that map to products. I want to add a second column that is foreign keys mapping to product categories. However, I only want the product category to be filled in if the product itself isn't filled in. Likewise, if the product category is filled in, I don't want the product to be filled in.

Is there some sort of way to say:

```
if(colA is NULL)
   colB is NOT NULL
if(colB is NULL)
   colA is NOT NULL
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `what's happening is not a good practice` The structure you're talking about doesn't sound like bad practice in and of itself. If you're misusing it, however, then you should probably seek an alternate solution.

Comment: @MartinCarney, I've edited and this makes me feel a little bit better. Alternate solutions have been explored that this is the one that requires minimal rewriting for the production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's MySQL, I guess creating a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger is your best bet. Example code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Validate_Trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF new.colA IS NOT NULL AND new.colB IS NOT NULL THEN        

        -- Disallowed: yhrow exception from trigger

        SET msg = 'Validate_Trigger: only one column can be NOT NULL: (colA, colB)';
        SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = msg;
    END IF;
END;
```

Usually in such cases you would create a `CHECK` constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
  ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName 
           CHECK (colA IS NULL OR colB IS NULL)
```

The problem here is that as of version 5.7, [MySQL ignores CHECK `constraints`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: Well, you certainly hate to see that a potential solution has been deprecated.

Comment: It's not deprecated. It has never been implemented properly by MySQL guys. Give me few minutes, I'll try to compose a trigger for you :)

Comment: Trigger code arrived. It was just out of my head, not sure if it compiles though, but I hope you'll get the idea.